# Run a script with Apache2 in a certain directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, lua

I am trying to run [WebMCP](http://www.public-software-group.org/webmcp) on an Apache2 server. It's got 2 executable files, which I have in /opt/webmcp/cgi-bin/webmcp.lua and /opt/webmcp/cgi-bin/webmcp-wrapper.lua

If I run the wrapper from a position that is not /opt/webmcp/cgi-bin it says it cannot find webmcp.lua and gives a 500 error.

[image]

If I run it from the correct directory it works.

My server has webmcp.lua set as directoryindex and it's giving 500 error. It may be because of this problem? /opt/webmcp/cgi-bin/ is already set as documentroot, and is accessible by www-data.

Comment: This question is off topic, as Super User is aimed at consumer computer usage. This question will be (hopefully) transfered by a moderator to our sister site, Server Fault.

Comment: "To improve the chances of your question staying open and getting an answer, make sure that it is about professional systems administration. If your question concerns personal equipment, try asking on Super User instead."